# Deploy a model from an R notebook in IBM Watson Studio

Tags: r, data-science-experience

I'm trying to find out how I can deploy an R notebook as a model in Watson Studio.

According the documentation, there is a bit of deployment code which needs to go in a cell of the notebook, however I can only find [documentation](https://dataplatform.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/ml-deploy-notebook.html) for Python and Scala.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a discussion with IBM support, I've found out that deploying R notebooks is still not supported. This is a feature which is in their backlog though, so it will hopefully come soon.

I'm posting this as an answer so other if other people have the same problem they can easily see this. However, if it should be a comment or an edit on my question, please let me know and I'll gladly change it.